# Spring Data Mongodb remove an array of document in other document

Tags: spring, mongodb

Example:

```
{
    "_id": "851504284360",
    "createUserId": "User73E68059D1A44EF3BBF88650EA3B83B0",
    "userIds": [],
    "userList": [
        {
            "_id": "User73E68059D1A44EF3BBF88650EA3B83B0",
            "phone": "kodD9QDWdTCl0KTTXjIRHw==",
            "token": "343cdbc09545e7e9812fea4998a83dd8"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to delete an array of document  in mongoDb ,but can't succeed in it. I've tried with `update.pull("userIds",value)`  succeed ,but the userList I've tried like :

```
update.pull("userList",new String[]{value}) ,
update.pull("userList",new ArrayList().add(Object)), 
update.pull("userList",new Object(key,value))//etc ...
```

but  can't succeed.

How can I  remove `userList` this document in spring mongodb ? I was use `mongoTemplate`.

Comment: in your attempt you are trying to pull(remove) boolean value, because new ArrayList().add(Object) will return boolean , and this value which will search by mongo in the document, definitely it wont find any boolean value to remove.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `userList` use [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator which deletes a particular field.

In Mongo you would do something like this:

```
db.collection.update(
   { "_id": "851504284360" },
   { "$unset": { "userList": "" } }
)
```

In mongoTemplate, you could do something like:

```
WriteResult wr = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(
     new Query(where("_id").is("851504284360")), 
     new Update().unset("userList"), 
     Entity.class
);
```